# How to use Site Design to remove default items from new sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, json, site-design

very new to SharePoint and I've been asked to set up new site design templates for SharePoint online. While I've managed well enough to create and add new site designs, I'm struggling with the specific JSON commands in the Site Script.

I'd like to remove several of the default elements from the Team layout (46, I believe?) such as the News and Activity sections. While removing navigation links has been straightforward with the removeNavLink verb, I'm not managing to find an equivalent for removing this default content - or at least not using it correctly.

I've looked over the JSON schema thoroughly, both Microsoft's page and the schema file itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it is not possible using site design and site script.

You might want to check if this is possible with [PnP provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine).